# How to make squircle shape in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

native ,just i to know how to make squircle in react-native ,i.e iphone 7 icons

help will be appreciated

Example

[image]

Comment: did you try https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg ?

Comment: i want to modify image on that kind of shape ,Image is coming from URL

Comment: GIve view a borderRadius and fill image with it

Comment: `<View style={{borderRadius:20,width:100,height:100,borderColor:"red",borderWidth:5}}></View>`

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#bordercurve-ios

> On iOS 13+, it is possible to change the corner curve of borders.